# Oracle Apex: RESTful Webservice not working after change of database schema

Tags: rest, web-services, restful-url, oracle-apex-5.1

I'm currently using APEX 18.1 and we created in our first database schema (db1) a RESTful Webservice (we provide a URL so other Application can send us data, so that we save them in the database). Now I changed the schema, to a new one (db2) and also already changed that in the shared components. 
But the data is still saving in the old schema and I dont know how I change the schema for the REST services. I already tried to put the schema name in front of my statements like `"INSERT INTO "db2".test VALUES (xyz)` but its not working.

Does someone have the same problem and a solution ?

Comment: I would try to recreate the service in the new schema. But if you tried to insert the data from the other schema, have you given the db1 schema grant to insert in db2 schema? > grant INSERT on "TEST" to db1 <

Comment: thanks for the answer. I guess it seems it was not my mistake but a bug of oracle in the implementation of the new 18.1 version. It is working not but still buggy